# How to use ament_ignore

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lets say in my src directory I have 5 packages wherein I dont want to build one...How can i use ament_ignore ?

```
ament build --symlink-install --AMENT_IGNORE package5
```

SOmething like this ? and what does symlink install do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292147/how-to-use-ament_ignore/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To skip building specific packages in your workspace you can use the `--skip-packages` argument for ament:
From `ament --help`:

```
  --skip-packages [SKIP_PACKAGES [SKIP_PACKAGES ...]]
                        Set of packages to skip
```

AMENT_IGNORE is a marker file that can be dropped in any directory of your workspace. This  will tell the build tool to not enter that directory. It is similar to ROS1's [CATKIN_IGNORE](https://answers.ros.org/question/208180/how-to-use-catkin_ignore-file-correctly/)

For more information about symlink install you can refer to the "Optional symlinked install" section of the [ament design article](http://design.ros2.org/articles/ament.html)

HTH

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1